# Adding bytes in python 2.7

Tags: python, binary, hex, byte, arrays

Hi I've been trying to iterate through a bytearray, add up all the bytes and then append the result back into the same bytearray. The bytearray looks like this: 
key = bytearray([0x12, 0x10, 0x32])
However, when I call sum(key) I get the decimal representation of 84. Any idea how I can change the decimal representation and put it back into a hexadecimal format while keeping it of type int. Thank You

Comment: The values in the array are the same whether they are represented in decimal or hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

A `bytearray` is always a list of integers. How they are displayed is only their representation. The same applies to the way you entered them. Python understand the `0x??` (hexadicimal) and `0??` (octal) notation for integers but it will display the decimal notation.

To convert an integer to a **string** in the `0x??` format use `hex(value)`.

Comment: okay thank you! I did't know that you could add a decimal number to a bytearray.